# How to morph text in openCV?

Tags: opencv, javacv

i want to morp some text in openCV/javacv like this:

[image: Image Hosted by ImageShack.us]

I know there are some functions like [warpPerspective](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/geometric_image_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#cvWarpPerspective), but i don't know how to use it to get these transform

greetings

Comment: You can implemented it yourself, take a look at function [`apply_wave()`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26595/CAPTCHA-Image-in-PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrapPerspective does perspective transformation. Probably you are looking for [remap](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap). Have a look at the example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364201/image-transformation-in-opencv/10374811#10374811) on stackoverflow. Hope that helps.