# Making an image curvy

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to transform an image such that straight lines/boxes become curvy.

Unfortunately I am only able to change the perspective of the images using Affine transformations. Which only makes line non-parallel if they were parallel before, the lines remain straight. I do not know which functions can bring curvy transformations.

```
hz_error,vert_error = 10,5
w,h,_=img.shape
src = np.float32([(0,0),(w,0),(w,h),(0,h)])
dst = np.float32([(-hz_error,-vert_error),(w+hz_error,-vert_error),(w-hz_error,h+vert_error),(0,h)])
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (w+20, h+20))
```

The input image
[image: Actual]
The output image
[image: Result]
The output that I require should be a curvy image.

An example desirable output,
[image: Desirable]
Here the edges are "curvy" rather than straight.

Comment: There are an infinite number of transformations that make lines curvy. Any idea on how they should curve?

Comment: Use a 4 point perspective transformation much the same as your affine but using 4 points rather than 3. That will slant the lines as per your desired "curvy" result. Note that your use of "curvy" is wrong. It is slanted (parallelogram) not curvy.

Comment: @fmw42 The code that I wrote only generates quadrilaterals because of the nature of the transform. If we apply perspective transform on a straight line it remain a straight line. I wanted a transformation which can make straight lines curvy. I added an example curvy image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I added an example desirable output image. It is basically cropped from a real image.

Comment: See remap as per `fireant` solution below.

Answer (score 2):

The most generic solution is to use [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gab75ef31ce5cdfb5c44b6da5f3b908ea4). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374811/1334399) on stackoverflow for a sample script that transform this image:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Those control points shown in red define the transformation. You'd set the first set of points on straight lines, and the destination points on curvy lines.