# How to correctly use griddata and cv2.remap for image transformation

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, interpolation

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10374811/5306861) answer, there is a code that uses `griddata` and `cv2.remap` to align an image with sudoku.

I'm trying to understand how it works, for this purpose I wrote the following code:

```py
#%%
import cv2
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
import numpy as np

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:5:6j, 0:5:6j]
source      = np.array([[2,2], [3,2], [2,1], [3,1]])
destination = np.array([[2,3], [3,3], [2,2], [3,2]])
grid_z = griddata(destination, source, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic', fill_value=0)
map_x = np.append([], [ar[:,1] for ar in grid_z]).reshape(6,6)
map_y = np.append([], [ar[:,0] for ar in grid_z]).reshape(6,6)
map_x_32 = map_x.astype('float32')
map_y_32 = map_y.astype('float32')

orig = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [1,1,1,1,1,1],
                 [1,1,1,1,1,1],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                 [0,0,0,0,0,0]], np.float32)
print("org")
print(orig)

warped = cv2.remap(orig, map_x_32, map_y_32, cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
print("warped")
print(np.round(warped))
```

In this code, instead of a sudoku image, I put a two-dimensional array of 6x6, but the result I got is not the result I expected.

```py
org
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
warped
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Since I move the 4 pixels in the center - downwards, I would expect to get something like this:

```py
warped
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

From the above answer, I understood that all I have to do is find source points, and give each point a target point and the image will change accordingly, and this is how it really happens in the sudoku image, but not in my code, where am I going wrong?

[image]

[image]