# Detecting Sudoku Square in an Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I would like to ask another question related to [How to remove convexity defects in a Sudoku square?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-sudoku-square)

I implemented a Sudoku Solver in OpenCV-Python and it work pretty good. But at this time, i made an assumption which will simplify my problem.

Assumption is : `Sudoku boundary(square) is the biggest blob in the input image`

Eg:

[image]

The red block is the detected square. You can see it covers the major part of the image.

**The Problem:**

Problem is nothing but the assumption. `If sudoku square has another square around it, method fails. Or if the image has another bigger blob than the sudoku square, again method fails.`

For eg, take this [image](http://tur.stparchive.com/Archive/TUR/TUR02132012p18.jpg). (I don't want to upload original image here, it is pretty big, also i want to upload the result anyway)

I tried several following methods to find sudoku square in this image:

1) `Find the biggest blob`

Then I got the red coloured region. `Method Failed`.

[image]

(Image is resized from original image to reduce size)

2) `Find only square regions`

You can see a lot of candidates are there, especially `KING CROSSWORD` which is all way similar to Sudoku. `Method again fails`

`In short, this image has everything, to fail me.`

**Question:**

`How to detect a sudoku square in an image, especially in the test image i gave? Is there any better algorithm for this?`

**UPDATE:** After reading some answers and comments, i think i should give an update. Look at the below image:

[image]

This image has a question sudoku and previous sudoku's answer. Both are alike. I think searching for sub-blocks or OCR testing won't work here.

Comment: A completely different and maybe useless method, but couldn't you push it through an OCR system, and look for a textual hint where to look first, and then go from there?

Comment: I don't think so. Check the update in the question.

Comment: Well, I did give it as a comment because I wasn't sure :) .. Still, I think you need to use multiple methods. One could be to find the general area of the sudoku by OCR (so you don't get the cartoons), and then find the biggest blob/square? something like that. Just thinking aloud ;)

Comment: To the update: technically both are Sudokus the second has been solved. So no empty blocks. I think you could detect it like this.

Answer (score 6):

Why not check every large square/blob?  Only the ones with 
1) 9X9 subsquares
2) Numbers in some of the subsquares
3) No blacked out subsquares
are sudoku.

Comment: and 4) Containing some blank squares?

Comment: I think the point @Chris and I sort of support is why not try everything that MIGHT be a sudoku and step through every one until determining it is not a sudoku?  You don't need to come up with some magic bullet that picks up the sudoku and only the sudoku from the page.