# Finding approximate rectangle in from a set of points

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, numpy

I have to extract an area from a image (can't disclose that image).
With the help of this [Abid K Rahman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square) I've obtained the image as
[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEn4g.png)
I've obtained the points of that may make a rectangle but couldn't find a rectangle which is the best approximate.

```
    [[625, 389], [10, 385], [116, 184], [5, 35], [626, 26]]
```

We can assume that all four points of the rectangle will be in four different corner of image. So I have divided the set into four different group based on their location.

```
    [[[[41, 63]], [[613, 66]]], [[[227, 428], [25, 426], [39, 392]], [[612, 394]]]]
```

But I'm not able to move further. I want to extract points which approximately makes a rectangle.
Better if the answer is in python.

Comment: Is that all you give us? You can learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch I've constraints. Though I have updated a little.

Comment: Any optimization problem requires constraints.  You have not specified any.  Would suggest trying to figure out a description of what your application will consider to be an appropriate rectangle.

Comment: I would suggest generalized hough transform.

Comment: Another method I can suggest is perhaps using RANSAC and using four points at a time, each time you test the pair wise angles with respect to each of the other points and also check for the largest amount of points contained in the rectangle. I haven't written an answer because I don't know if this will work.

Comment: @rayryeng will look into its implementation.

Comment: If I have time, I'll look into it and make an answer. It's an interesting problem.

Comment: @rayryeng I applied a basic way, though it is not upto the mark. You can find my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went on to write my the code using something [rayryeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3250829/rayryeng) suggested and come up with this.

```
c = [[[] for x in range(2)] for y in range (2)]
for xy in centroids:
    x_i = xy[0]*2/col
    y_i = xy[1]*2/row
    c[y_i][x_i].append(np.array(xy))

combination = []
combination = np.array([ np.array([q1,q2,q3,q4]) for q1 in c[0][0] for q2 in c[0][1] for q3 in c[1][1] for q4 in c[1][0]])

if len(combination)>0 :
    key = 0
    property = [[ 0 for j in range(4)] for i in range(len(combination))]
    for i in range(len(combination)):
        q = combination[i]
        d1,d2 = q[2]-q[0],q[1]-q[3]
        d1_len,d2_len = np.sqrt(sum(d1**2)),np.sqrt(sum(d2**2))
        angle = math.degrees(math.acos(sum(d1*d2)/(d1_len*d2_len)))
        if d1_len > d2_len:
            r,extent = int(100*d1_len/d2_len),d2_len
        else:
            r,extent = int(100*d2_len/d1_len),d1_len
        property[i] = [r,angle,extent,i]
    property.sort(key = lambda x:x[0])
    key = property[0][3]
    combination = combination[key]
```

Here centroids is the points I have got, which I divided in to quadrants, since in my problem the points need to be from all four qaudrants. I've made the all possible combination of four points.
I found the diagonals, the angle the make at the centre.
Made a list of which contain the ratio of length of diagonal(smallest to largest), the angle and the length of shortest diagonal.
I used the property that the diagonal of rectangle are of equal length. Which is quite useful for now. I don't know how to use the other properties hence its kept on hold. In final answer I get the best rectangle (when there are no points to make a sqaure, also, it doesn't care about the size of rectangle).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Python Shapely library can help.

Example:

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
points = MultiPoint([(0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0), ... ])

points.bounds
# A (minx, miny, maxx, maxy) tuple.
```

Answer (score -2):

best thing is `imcrop(I,rect);` where rect is define as

rect=[xmin ymin width height]

so at first pair for example [41,63],[613,66]

xmin=41

ymin=63

width=613-41

height=66-63

Comment: Again not the right answer. Read the question again carefully. The rectangle needs to be automatically defined given a set of points.