# finding predecessor and successor of a node(shape) in relation diagram

Tags: python, opencv, nodes

Finding predecessor and successor of a node(shape) in image:(opencv & python)

- read image [Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beze1.jpg)
- preprocessing of image
- segmentation for text and geometric shape extraction
- shape recognition (nodes and directed edges)
  [output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdf1G.jpg)

Now I want to get the junction point of node and edge so that to count indgree and out degree of node(shape) and then predecessor/successor of node

help somebody to get the relation b/w nodes and edges(lines)

I have tried to separate H/V lines using [How to remove convexity defects in a Sudoku square?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square)  but not able to get the junction points of node and edge

Comment: Since you were able to separate the H/V lines, you can perform **bitwise AND** operation between this image and the image containing only the shapes.

Comment: U mean to say : bitwise And of input image and image with H/V lines

Comment: No. What I meant was bitwise AND operation between the H/V lines image an the image containing only the shapes without lines

Comment: getting blank image after performing bitwise _and operation on shape_img and edges_img. Please help to get the junction point of shapes and edges.

Comment: Still on same stage, please help to get the solotion

Comment: Is it so tough to solve it?