# Extracting table structures from image

Tags: opencv

I have a bunch of images like[image: Table Sample]

What would be the good way to extract just the table structure from the image? I'm only interested extracting the straight lines.

I have been toying around with [OpenCV Finding Contours](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) code sample and the results are quite promising. I'm just wondering if there is maybe a better way?

Comment: May you could try also [HoughLineTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html), get all **horizontal lines** and get ROI based on minimum y and max x coordinates (basically two diagonal corners of the ROI - rectangle here)

Comment: I have tried http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html  but the result is pretty bad.

Comment: Ok that is strange, so if I understand correctly, you want to extract just the table in between right?

Comment: I just like to extract the grid of horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: In that case you could also try [CCA](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gae57b028a2b2ca327227c2399a9d53241)

Comment: This looks like worth a try! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square/10226971#10226971

Answer (score 6):

OpenCV has a nice way to detect line segments. Here is a code snippet in python:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('page2.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

lsd = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(0)
dlines = lsd.detect(gray)

for dline in dlines[0]:
    x0 = int(round(dline[0][0]))
    y0 = int(round(dline[0][1]))
    x1 = int(round(dline[0][2]))
    y1 = int(round(dline[0][3]))
    cv2.line(img, (x0, y0), (x1,y1), 255, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

    # print line segment length
    a = (x0-x1) * (x0-x1)
    b = (y0-y1) * (y0-y1)
    c = a + b
    print(math.sqrt(c))

cv2.imwrite('page2_lines.png', img)
```

Comment: I wonder how to extract a segment, created by your code. Any suggesstions?

Comment: This doesnt give me all the lines segments in the table :( is there any quick fix for the code ?

Answer (score 2):

Kindly go through my Github repository [Code for table extraction](https://github.com/Iamsunilsharma/Stackoverflow-Answers/blob/master/How%20data%20is%20extracted%20from%20a%20data%20table%20in%20the%20form%20of%20an%20image%20using%20OCRs.ipynb)

The developed code detect table and extract out information by keeping the spatial coordinates intact. [image]

The code detects lines from tables as shown in an image below. I hope it solves your problem. 
[image]

The extracted output in terms of a table is shown below.[image]