# OpenCV 3: What's the issue with Perspective Transformation in openCV 3.3.1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.3

I am trying perspective transformation example from the documentation but I am getting different result than the example.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('sudoku.png')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape
pts1 = np.float32([[56,65],[368,52],[28,387],[389,390]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[0,300],[300,300]])
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,M,(300,300))
plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

The result according to the example should look like
 (ignore the green lines)
[image]

whereas what I got looks like

[image]

Any ideas what's going on here? I am on macOS 10.13, openCV 3.3.1 and using python 3.6

Comment: What's the size of the input image? How did you selected the pts1 points?

Comment: It was all given in the documentation example.

Comment: You can clearly see from the x,y axis that you image is bigger than the one you show with the green cross... Come on, a little effort...

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong coords.

```
## sudo.png (563, 558, 3)

## tl->tr->br->bl
pts1 = np.float32([[76,85],[490,70],[520,520],[35,512]])
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[300,0],[300,300], [0,300]])
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using matplotlib to plot? I am still not getting the result.

Comment: the correct order that worked for me is tl -> tr -> bl -> br

Comment: And are you still trapped in this? Here is an interesting post for more advanced topic, I'm trying to solve it. You can have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square/11366549