# How can I improve template matching for number recognization?

Tags: python, computer-vision

So i want to recognize the numbers of a sudoko by doing a template matching.
For some of the photos, the template matching goes well, but for some images it goes wrong, what should I do to improve the precision? I read that i should improve my templates but i don't know what to do anymore.
I attach function where i do matching and also my github repo for the rest of the project.
input:
[image]

and the file as failure
[image]

Thanks!

def get_results(img,lines_horizontal,lines_vertical):
#k=0
for i in range(len(lines_horizontal)-1):
for j in range(len(lines_vertical)-1):
y_min = lines_vertical[j][0][0]
y_max = lines_vertical[j + 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbyYW.png)[0]
x_min = lines_horizontal[i][0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbyYW.png)
x_max = lines_horizontal[i + 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbyYW.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbyYW.png)
patch = img_crop[x_min:x_max, y_min:y_max].copy()

```
           # w, h = template[4].shape[::-1]
            img_gray = cv.cvtColor(patch, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            threshold = 0.9

            # Store the coordinates of matched area in a numpy array
            # Draw a rectangle around the matched region.
            # Show the final image with the matched area.
            #cv.imshow('Detected',patch)
            patch_2=img_crop[x_min+17:x_max-12,y_min+12:y_max-18].copy()
           # cv.imshow("patch", patch_2)
            #k+=1
            image = cv.cvtColor(patch_2,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            image_m_blur = cv.medianBlur(image,5)
            image_g_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(image_m_blur, (0, 0), 5) 
            image_sharpened = cv.addWeighted(image_m_blur, 1.2, image_g_blur, -0.8, 0)
            _, thresh = cv.threshold(image_sharpened, 20, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)
            kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
            thresh = cv.erode(thresh, kernel)
            img_gray=cv.cvtColor(patch,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            img_grayt=cv.normalize(img_gray,None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv.NORM_MINMAX)
            img_grayt=img_grayt[2:-2,8:-8]
            #cv.imshow("patch", thresh)
            print(np.mean(thresh))
            #show_image("patch",img_grayt)
            if(np.mean(thresh)>253):
                f.write("o")
                g.write("o")
            else:
                f.write("x")
                ok=0
                while ok!=1:
                    for k in range(0,9):
                        res = cv.matchTemplate(img_grayt,template[k],cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
                        show_image("template",template[k])
                        show_image("patch",img_grayt)
                        loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
                        if len(loc[0]>1):
                            g.write(str(k+1))
                            ok=1
                            break
                    threshold-=0.03
                
            cv.waitKey(0)
            cv.destroyAllWindows()
        f.write("\n")
        g.write("\n")
```

https://github.com/teocaragea/Sudoku-

Comment: you need to provide a [mre], which includes inputs for which it "fails" (and show how it fails)

Comment: i update the original post

Comment: OpenCV's `matchTemplate` is *unsuitable*. you have a *photo*, which means perspective distortion and lower-dimensional distortions.

Comment: so basically i can't do anything to improve it?

Comment: it'll kinda work but basically it's the wrong tool for the job. it can't even test different scales. -- why don't you use OCR? -- why don't you first localize the grid and warp the image so the grid aligns with a straight reference?

Comment: well, this is what i do, first i localize the grid.I don't know how to use something else, can you show me an exemple or anything?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196198/how-to-remove-convexity-defects-in-a-sudoku-square