# How to get a differently oriented sub-image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to take a **sub-image from a bigger image**, but I have the 4 corners of the image and I want to get the resulting image, **independently of the orientation it may have**.

Is there a Matlab function to make this? I can't seem to find one.

There is a similar question for `opencv` and `python`, check for more clarity-> [How to straighten a rotated rectangle area of an image using opencv in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627362/how-to-straighten-a-rotated-rectangle-area-of-an-image-using-opencv-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can programmatically select a rectangle using [`impoly`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impoly.html) or similar, then obtain the angle and use `imrotate` to align the subimage.

Comment: thats nice, but I need to do it programaticaly, the corners are extracted with other functions before.

Comment: I don't understand the problem with this answer. If you have the corners then you already know what the angle is, right?

Comment: yes I agree... Also, if the corners aren't creating a rotated rectangle but some trapezoid then the rotation angle is not well defined. So one needs to take the mean value of the angles etc...

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin and naten. Yeah, I was a little big vague in my question sorry. My problem is that the points are not creating a perfect square. Still this question is directly related to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342164/how-to-plot-a-surface-with-a-texture-map . So If you want to continue with the topic, the answer to the trapezoids may help you get 50 reputation :D