# How to plot a surface with a texture map

Tags: matlab, image-processing, texture-mapping, geometry-surface

I want to plot a surface with a texture map on it, but the conditions are not the "ideal" ones.

first lets explain what I have.

I have a set of points (~7000) that are image coordinates, in a grid. **This points do NOT define perfect squares.**  **IT IS NOT A MESHGRID**. For the sake of the question, lets assume that we have 9 points. Lets ilustrate what we have with an image:

```
 X=[310,270,330,430,410,400,480,500,520]
 Y=[300,400,500,300,400,500,300,400,500]
```

[image]
Lets say we can get the "structure" of the grid, so

```
 size1=3;
 size2=3;
 points=zeros(size1,size2,2)
 X=[310,270,330;
    430,410,400;
    480,500,520]
 Y=[300,400,500;
    300,400,500;
    300,400,500]
 points(:,:,1)=X;
 points(:,:,2)=Y;
```

And now lets say we have a 3rd dimension, Z.

**EDIT:** Forgot to add a piece if info. I triangulate the points in the image and get a 3D correspondence, so when displayed in a surface they don't have the X and Y coords of the image, for a simplification of the given data lets say X=X/2 Y=Y/3

And we have:

```
 points=zeros(size1,size2,3)
 Z=[300,330,340;
    300,310,330;
    290,300,300]

 surf(points(:,:,1)/2,points(:,:,2)/3,points(:,:,3))
```

[image]

What I want is to plot the surface in 3D with the image texture. Each element should have the texture piece that have in the first image.

This needs to work for huge datasheets. I don't specially need it to be fast.

related post (but I has a meshgrid as initial set of points) : [Texture map for a 2D grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239667/texture-map-for-a-2d-grid)

**PD:** I can post original images + real data if needed, just posted this because i think it is easier with small data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want with Matlab's built in commands and features. But using the technique from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16426386/1339280) with a high-res version of the grid can do it for you.

By "high-res", I mean an interpolated version of the non-uniform grid with denser data points. That is used to sample the texture at denser data points so it can be drawn using the `texturemap` feature of `surf`. You can't use a normal 2D interpolation, however, because you need to preserve the non-uniform grid shape. This is what I came up with:

```
function g = nonUniformGridInterp2(g, sx, sy)

[a,b] = size(g);
g = interp1(linspace(0,1,a), g, linspace(0,1,sy)); % interp columns
g = interp1(linspace(0,1,b), g', linspace(0,1,sx))'; % interp rows
```

Note that you have to call this twice to interpolate the X and Y points independently. Here's an example of the original grid and an interpolated version with 10 points in each direction.

[image: Plot of the original and interpolated grids]

Here's how to use that high-res grid with `interp2` and `texturemap`.

```
function nonUniformTextureMap

% define the non-uniform surface grid
X = [310,270,330; 430,410,400; 480,500,520];
Y = [300,400,500; 300,400,500; 300,400,500];
Z = [300,330,340; 300,310,330; 290,300,300];

% get texture data
load penny % loads data in variable P

% define texture grid based on image size
% note: using 250-550 so that a,b covers the range used by X,Y
[m,n] = size(P);
[a,b] = meshgrid(linspace(250,550,n), linspace(250,550,m));

% get a high-res version of the non-uniform grid
s = 200; % number of samples in each direction
X2 = nonUniformGridInterp2(X, s, s);
Y2 = nonUniformGridInterp2(Y, s, s);

% sample (map) the texture on the non-uniform grid
C = interp2(a, b, P, X2, Y2);

% plot the original and high-res grid
figure
plot(X(:),Y(:),'o',X2(:),Y2(:),'.')
legend('original','high-res')

% plot the surface using sampled points for color
figure
surf(X, Y, Z, C, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'FaceColor','texturemap')
colormap gray
```

[image: Plot of the mapped texture]

Comment: Awesome dude. I liek the idea. I will try to do smthing like this, it may work very well. Still, just to know, How long did it take to do that? seems fast also!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks! The code just took a few minutes to write after I got the idea. It is nice and fast for this little data set. How's it going with your "huge" data set?

Comment: I still dint' achieve to plot it, as it is a little bit mroe complex, but the idea is right and it should work!

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `texturemap` property of `surf` which works with rectangular meshes as well as with non-rectangular ones.

Creating non-rectangular data points

```
% creating non-rectangular data points
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:100, 1:100);
X = X+rand(size(X))*5; 
Y = Y+rand(size(X))*5;
```

which results in the following data points:

[image]

Generating height data:

```
Z = sin(X/max(X(:))*2*pi).*sin(Y/max(Y(:))*2*pi);
```

[image]

Loading picture:

```
[imageTest]=imread('peppers.png');
```

[image]

and mapping it as texture to the mesh:

```
surf(X,Y,Z, imageTest, ...
     'edgecolor', 'none','FaceColor','texturemap')
```

[image]

Note that, for the sake of demonstration, this non-rectangular grid is quite sparsely populated which results in a rather jagged texture. With more points, the result gets much better, irrespective of the distortion of the grid points.

Note also that the number of grid points does not have to match the number of pixels in the texture image.

**~edit~**

If X and Y coordinates are only available for parts of the image, you can adjust the texture accordingly by

```
minX = round(min(X(:)));
maxX = round(max(X(:))); 
minY = round(min(Y(:)));
maxY = round(max(Y(:)));

surf(X,Y,Z, imageTest(minX:maxX, minY:maxY, :), ...
     'edgecolor', 'none','FaceColor','texturemap')
```

Comment: what about not using a meshgrid? I know how to do it with a meshgrid, you can see it in the link I posted in my question. Sorry this does not answer the question

Comment: @AnderBiguri: please see my updated answer and pardon me for not reading your question carefully enough in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks H.Muster. I forgot to add a little detail of the surface grid, please check my edit. I think the change is small for your answer, but I cant seem to find the answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: The grid coordinates do not have to match the texture coordinates. As long as you do not perform non-linear transformations on the grid points, the texture should be mapped to the grid points irrespectively of transformations.

Comment: I tested your answer. It goes in the rigth direction but it is not the correct one (at leas not in my test!). It seems that the WHOLE texture is plotted in the surface, but it is not what i want. I want only the texture corresponding to each element to be ploted. So in the image2 i posted in my question the texture to plot should be the texture that corresponds to the squares in imgage1. Thats why i noted the changed pixel correspondence, as it should matter.

Comment: Sorry, but still what you are doing is get a SQUARE piece of the image. I need the texture of each element to be the one corresponding in the image. It is true that this last edit of your answer come much closer to the desired one. For example imagine the points are in a circle shape, or even a "growing moon" shape. Your answer does not work in that case.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Sorry, but I don't think that the texture property of the `surf` function will work for non-rectangular textures. Though, I do not know it for sure...

Comment: Yeah, I know is not easy... Thats why i started a bounty. My first idea was to get every texture piece separatedly and then plot it in a for loop, but dont know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think that what you need to do is sample (map) the texture at your grid's X,Y points. Then you can simply plot the surface and use those samples as colors.

Here's an example using the data you gave in your question. It doesn't look like much, but using more X,Y,Z points should give the result you're after.

```
% define the non-uniform surface grid
X = [310,270,330; 430,410,400; 480,500,520];
Y = [300,400,500; 300,400,500; 300,400,500];
Z = [300,330,340; 300,310,330; 290,300,300];

% get texture data
load penny % loads data in variable P

% define texture grid based on image size
% note: using 600 so that a,b covers the range used by X,Y
[m,n] = size(P);
[a,b] = meshgrid(linspace(0,600,n), linspace(0,600,m));

% sample (map) the texture on the non-uniform grid
C = interp2(a, b, P, X, Y);

% plot the surface using sampled points for color
figure
surf(X, Y, Z, C)
colormap gray
```

[image: Plot of the mapped texture]

Comment: No, Thats not what I want, sorry. I want the texture itself plotted in this surface. You just plotted a colour, but between 4 points there is a whole texture there. I want to extract the texture of each element in the first image to plot it (as a texture, no as a colour) in each element of the surface.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Now I understand! Please see my new answer.