# Create a Contour Plot from Two Matrices

Tags: matlab, plot, contour

I am having difficulty producing a contour plot from two matrices;

I have one matrix `A` 9×8 with values (an amount of something), and another matrix 9×8 `B` where each entry corresponds to a location of an entry in `A`.

The issue is that the entries do not fall on a rectangular grid.

I'm trying to create a contour plot of the Y-Axis values (from matrix `A`), based on the X-axis values from matrix `B`.

I've tried `meshgrid` (based on the x and y ranges for `B`), however the values in matrix `B` are not evenly spaced;

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you have this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342164/how-to-plot-a-surface-with-a-texture-map

Comment: You might have to settle with interpolation.  Check [`scatteredInterpolant`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant-class.html) for more details.

Comment: Indeed, I've managed to come up with a contour using the scatteredInterpolant. However, my contour result is extremely sensitive to how I define my x and y vectors which define my meshgrid. Furthermore, the final contour plot is close, but does not succeed in showing the highest values from my matrix(B). Is it possible to not use a linear interpolation?