# How to add border around an image in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

If I have an image like below, how can I add border all around the image such that the overall height and width of the final image increases but the height and width of the original image stays as-is in the middle.

[image]

Comment: How about [cv2.copyMakeBorder](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#void%20copyMakeBorder%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20top,%20int%20bottom,%20int%20left,%20int%20right,%20int%20borderType,%20const%20Scalar&%20value%29) ?

Comment: By the way, opencv official documentation provides a [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html) how to append a border to am image using cv2.copyMakeBorder.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The following code adds a constant border of size `10` pixels to all four sides of your original image.

For the colour, I have assumed that you want to use the average gray value of the background, which I have calculated from the mean value of bottom two lines of your image. Sorry, somewhat hard coded, but shows the general how-to and can be adapted to your needs.

If you leave `border_size` values for bottom and right at `0`, you even get a symmetric border.

Other values for `BORDER_TYPE` are possible, such as `BORDER_DEFAULT`, `BORDER_REPLICATE`, `BORDER_WRAP`.

For more details cf: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html#gsc.tab=0

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
row, col = im.shape[:2]
bottom = im[row-2:row, 0:col]
mean = cv2.mean(bottom)[0]

border_size = 10
border = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
    im,
    top=border_size,
    bottom=border_size,
    left=border_size,
    right=border_size,
    borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,
    value=[mean, mean, mean]
)

cv2.imshow('image', im)
cv2.imshow('bottom', bottom)
cv2.imshow('border', border)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Using the tutorial I thought that the value for Red (confusingly labelled Blue) should be [255, 0, 0].  But actually it was [1.0, 0, 0] with floats as the image value colours.

Answer (score 21):

Answer in one line

```
outputImage = cv2.copyMakeBorder(
                 inputImage, 
                 topBorderWidth, 
                 bottomBorderWidth, 
                 leftBorderWidth, 
                 rightBorderWidth, 
                 cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, 
                 value=color of border
              )
```

Answer (score 16):

Try This:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np     

img=cv2.imread("img_src.jpg")
h,w=img.shape[0:2]

base_size=h+20,w+20,3
# make a 3 channel image for base which is slightly larger than target img
base=np.zeros(base_size,dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.rectangle(base,(0,0),(w+20,h+20),(255,255,255),30) # really thick white rectangle
base[10:h+10,10:w+10]=img # this works
```

Answer (score 8):

Add border using openCV

```
import cv2
white = [255,255,255]
img1 = cv2.imread('input.png')
constant= cv2.copyMakeBorder(img1,20,20,20,20,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value=white)
cv2.imwrite('output.png',constant)
```