# pytesseract struggling to recognize clean black and white pictures with font numbers and 7 seg digits(python)

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, python-tesseract

I've been trying to get tesseract to recognize the numbers on this image:
[image: Filtered Img]

but when running the script the output is empty meaning it can't

Any idea how to make it work? it doesn't seem like it should have a bad time converting the image into text and the same happens 7 segment digital digits
and when trying to run tesseract on a noisier colored version of this image this does actually seem to work well in this example:

[image: Noisy img]

Any hints on how to get it to work?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try to add white border ~20pix around your filtered image

Comment: Yes! success that works! please post this as an answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: Any clue about the 7 segment font issue?

Answer (score 1):

Tesseract is very sensitive to the image borders, so adding about 20 pix border around your filtered image will solve the issue.

Regarding 7-segment font as stated in tesseract issue - [LSTM (tess 4.*) might not be the best approach](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata/issues/65#issuecomment-323254578) and there are different libraries which can handle this better. You can try [this tessdata](https://github.com/arturaugusto/display_ocr/tree/master/letsgodigital) for tesseract 3.4;