# Opencv Python: How to detect filled, rectangular shapes on picture

Tags: python, opencv

I have the picture below.
I want to find the the black colored rectangles on the left using opencv. Thanks for help=)
[image]

Comment: Please provide more detail. As it currently reads, your question doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's [a simple approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59994134/50065) using thresholding + morphological operations.

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load image, convert to grayscale, then adaptive threshold
2. **Fill rectangular contours.** Find contours and fill the contours to create filled rectangular blocks.
3. **Perform morph open.** We create a rectangular structuring element and morph open to remove the lines
4. **Draw rectangles around largest rectangles** Find contours and draw bounding rectangles around rectangles with an area above a certain treshold.

---

Here's each step visualized:

Obtain binary image

[image]

Adaptive treshold

[image]

Filled rectangular contours

[image]

Perform morph open

[image]

Draw rectangles around largest rectangles

[image]

In code:

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2

#load the image
image = cv2.imread("mtF6y.jpg")

# grayscale
result = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# adaptive threshold
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,51,9)

# Fill rectangular contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Morph open
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=4)

# Draw rectangles, the 'area_treshold' value was determined empirically
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
area_treshold = 4000
for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > area_treshold :
      x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
      cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```