# how to remove the white pixel around the image?

Tags: image, coordinates, crop, pixel, grayscale

How I can corp the image or other methods so that the summation of pixels in the boundary, be less than the hole x and y position. I mean in the images below

the white hole summation x and y of the pixels must be higher in the hole position but as shown in the chart the surrounding of the image especially the x summation of pixels have the higher summation

In this way, I want to found the sum pixels that have high values and illustrate the hole pixels or coordination.  In the y-axis, the summation of course so as the below better result than the x one but in some others not, of course, I crop all of 1000 image by below code then after returning the pixel data sum of them and the id and the max values than return the hole is illustrated.

```
img = Image.open('J:\py.pro\path\picture_1.png').convert('L')  # convert image to 8-bit grayscale

if img.mode == "CMYK":
    # color profiles can be found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Adobe\Color\Profiles\Recommended
    img = ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, "USWebCoatedSWOP.icc", "sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm", outputMode="RGB")
# PIL image -> OpenCV image; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/14134892/2202732
img = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

## (1) Convert to gray, and threshold
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

## (2) Morph-op to remove noise
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (10,30))
morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(threshed, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

## (3) Find the max-area contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(morphed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
cnt = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]

## (4) Crop and save it
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
dst = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

# add border/padding around the cropped image
# dst = cv2.copyMakeBorder(dst, 10, 10, 10, 10, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=[255,255,255])

#cv2.imshow("J:\\py.pro\\path\\pic_1.png", dst)
cv2.imwrite("J:\\py.pro\\path\\pic_1.png", dst)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

How about adding a 1-pixel wide white border on all sides and flood-filling white-coloured pixels with black starting from (0,0) so that the flood-fill flows around the edges filling all white areas at image edges?

I'll demonstrate with magenta for the flood-fill so you can see which pixels are affected:

[image]

---

I actually did that with **ImageMagick** in Terminal, but you can do just the same with **OpenCV**:

```
magick lattice.png -bordercolor white -border 1 -fill magenta -draw 'color 0,0 floodfill' result.png
```

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your code does it a python code and is it possible to add it to the program?

Comment: Does identifying the magenta pixels help you?

Comment: Apparently, The chart shows the effect of it on bourders

Comment: But how I can apply to all images? does it possible to do it by crop and shade the white of boundary or transparent it?

Comment: Ok, you can use `copyMakeBorder()` to add a 1-pixel white border all the way around  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36259457/2836621 or create a white image 2 pixels taller and 2 pixels wider than your initial image then paste in your original image starting at (1,1). Then use `floodFill()`

Comment: Thanks, let me check your guidance and help, and if I get confused, I will let you know again

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, you are a great helper and also excellent in image processing with your help I can handle the images