# How does cv2.boundingRect() function of OpenCV work?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I need the explanation on boundingRect of OpenCV. I have used  it, it works great. Is there any reference where this function is fully explained please?

Comment: Have you seen [THIS DOC](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html)

Comment: @JeruLuke : Yes, I did went through it several times. But i need more information about how it works in the background.

Comment: It gets the min and max locations of the contour in both x and y.  Those define the bounding box. left=min_x, top=min_y, width=(max_x-min_x), height=(max_y-min_y)

Answer (score 33):

The `cv2.boundingRect()` function of OpenCV is used to draw an approximate rectangle around the binary image. This function is used mainly to highlight the region of interest after obtaining contours from an image.

As per [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) there are two types of bounding rectangles:

1. **Straight Bounding Rectangle**

Here a simple rectangle is drawn around the contour (ROI). As you can see in the documentation, a green rectangle is drawn around the ROI. Corresponding rectangle coordinates are obtained such that a rectangle completely encloses the contour.

2. **Rotated Rectangle**

- In this case `cv2.minAreaRect()` function is used to highlight the
  minimum rectangular area enclosing a contour.
- `cv2.boxPoints()` obtains the 4 corner points of the obtained
  rectangle.
- `np.int0()` is done to convert the corrdinates from `float` to
  `integer` format.
- These points are then used to draw the rectangle. This is depicted by
  the red rectangle in the documentation.

Comment: "draw" and "highlight" would be inaccurate, as those funcions only return objects, but don't draw in the image (you can use them to do that with other functions, though).

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54823710/11573842) answer to be useful. You can refer to it. It demonstrates what Jeru describes here.

Answer (score 0):

just find `min_x , min_y , max_x, max_y` by looping over the points in the contour, and calculate the width `max_x - min_x` and height `max_y - min_y`