# Rotate a detected rectangle in openCV Java

Tags: android, image, opencv

I have been searching the internet for a while now. The problem is that the solution to my problem in mostly available in either python or C++. I have tried to replicate the code but no luck.

I have detected a card (Rectangle) and I am able to crop it if the rectangle is straight but if the rectangle is rotated at an angle I get a image that cuts the card.

Image showing what I want to achieve...

[image: What I want to achieve]

My working code for straight Image.

```
Bitmap abc = null;
Point topleft, topright, bottomleft, bottomright;

float xRatio = (float) original.getWidth() / sourceImageView.getWidth();
float yRatio = (float) original.getHeight() / sourceImageView.getHeight();

float x1 = (points.get(0).x) * xRatio;
float x2 = (points.get(1).x) * xRatio;
float x3 = (points.get(2).x) * xRatio;
float x4 = (points.get(3).x) * xRatio;
float y1 = (points.get(0).y) * yRatio;
float y2 = (points.get(1).y) * yRatio;
float y3 = (points.get(2).y) * yRatio;
float y4 = (points.get(3).y) * yRatio;

Point p1 = new Point(x1, y1);
Point p2 = new Point(x2, y2);
Point p3 = new Point(x3, y3);
Point p4 = new Point(x4, y4);
List<Point> newpoints = new ArrayList<Point>();
newpoints.add(p1);
newpoints.add(p2);
newpoints.add(p3);
newpoints.add(p4);
Collections.sort(newpoints, new Comparator<Point>() {

    public int compare(Point o1, Point o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1.x, o2.x);
    }
});
if (newpoints.get(0).y > newpoints.get(1).y) {

    bottomleft = newpoints.get(0);
    topleft = newpoints.get(1);
} else {
    bottomleft = newpoints.get(1);
    topleft = newpoints.get(0);
}
if (newpoints.get(2).y > newpoints.get(3).y) {
    bottomright = newpoints.get(2);
    topright = newpoints.get(3);
} else {
    bottomright = newpoints.get(3);
    topright = newpoints.get(2);
}
final Mat newimage = new Mat();
Bitmap bmp32 = original.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp32, newimage);
final float dd = getAngle(bottomleft, bottomright);

Mat finalMat = new Mat(newimage, new org.opencv.core.Rect(topleft, bottomright));
abc = RotateBitmap(createBitmapfromMat(finalMat), (-dd));
```

Current code when rectangle is straight :

[image]
[image]

Current code when rectangle is rotated:

[image]
[image]

Links to similar questions :
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11627362/how-to-straighten-a-rotated-rectangle-area-of-an-image-using-opencv-in-python)  [Link 2](http://answers.opencv.org/question/69758/aligment-plate-or-rotatedrect-and-draw/)

Comment: and in which step are you stuck? describe a little bit more your problem, like I do not know how to do x instruction in C++ in java.... I think you need to use functions like findHomography and warpAffine from OpenCV to achieve the similar result... I do not see those in your code

Comment: The rectangle I want to crop is rotated and when I crop it using the above method the rectangle get cut and I want the complete rectangle

Comment: can you add an image of your current result?

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: you crop before rotating the image... you should crop after the rotation

Comment: Your rotation looks fine. Seems like you just crop at the wrong coordinates.

Comment: @api55 if I crop after image rotation the rectangle with not be at the detected points.

Comment: @TA I know that, I need to know how do I get the correct coordinates after Image rotation

Comment: If you know the image coodinates before your rotation as well as the magnitude of the rotation you can easily calculate your resulting coordinates using a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)