# How to fix transform perspective function incorrectly returning image in the wrong orientation

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

Please help me understand why this happened and if possible provide a better, more robust solution than my patch.

The function is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58423570/7657721). The problem is, there is a case where an image contour is warped incorrectly in the wrong orientation: it was already right side up before the fixed rotation code. Therefore when it is returned its oriented incorrectly with its top side to the left. The contour is rectangular (about 2991 x 2025 on its correct orientation) and is identified correctly as width-wise.

The function is mostly there just to straighten the orientation of the cropped rectangular contour as much as possible; there is no extreme cases where it needs to be rotated >45 degrees either way as there's another function before this that takes care of that. The image is always rectangular, never square, and whether it's in landscape (width>height) or portrait (height>width) is accounted for in the code. You can see its use case on the link above.

Here is the code:

```
def transform_perspective(img, corners):
    def reorder_corner_points(corners):
        tr, tl, bl, br = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners][0:4]
        return tl, tr, br, bl

    # order the points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = reorder_corner_points(corners)
    tl, tr, br, bl = ordered_corners

    # determine width of new image which is the max distance between
    # (bottom right and bottom left) or (top right and top left) x-coordinates
    width_A = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    width_B = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    width = max(int(width_A), int(width_B))

    # determine height of new image which is the max distance between
    # (top right and bottom right) or (top left and bottom left) y-coordinates
    height_A = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    height_B = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    height = max(int(height_A), int(height_B))

    # construct new points to obtain top-down view of image in
    # tr, tl, bl, br order
    dimensions = np.array([[0, 0], [width - 1, 0], [width - 1, height - 1],
                           [0, height - 1]], dtype="float32")

    # convert to numpy format
    ordered_corners = np.array(ordered_corners, dtype="float32")

    # find perspective transform matrix
    matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(ordered_corners, dimensions)

    # get the transformed image,
    # should be its right side up is facing to the right,
    # height = img.shape[0] > width = img.shape[1]
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, matrix, (width, height))

    # "rotate" -90 degrees to correct orientation
    warped = cv2.transpose(warped)
    warped = cv2.flip(warped, 0)

    return warped
```

My patch is to simply add this `if`statement before the fixed rotation:

```
        # rotate the transformed image
        # rotate counter-clockwise once if landscape and length is greater than height
        # so that the fields to be extracted and read are right side up
        # skip rotating if it's already right side up for some reason.
        if (warped.shape[0] > warped.shape[1]) and config.is_landscape:
            warped = cv2.transpose(warped)
            warped = cv2.flip(warped, 0)
```

Where, since the image is landscape, `config.is_landscape` is set to `True`. And to account for the other case:

```
        if (warped.shape[0] < warped.shape[1]) and not config.is_landscape:
            warped = cv2.transpose(warped)
            warped = cv2.flip(warped, 0)
```

Whole code to replicate pre-processing etc. Paste after the function from above.

```
# read and preprocess image
image = cv2.imread('asdasd.png', 1)
original = image.copy()
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(image,9,75,75)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# get all contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# get the largest contour
cnt = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

# warp
peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
transformed = transform_perspective(original, cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.05 * peri, True))

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('transformed', transformed)
# cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The image that broke my code:
[image: the image that broke my code]

I honestly don't know what's special or different with this image and contour that it breaks the code. See the image from the previous post for a comparison. Most of my other images behave similarly like the latter too.

Comment: Maybe the row of black pixels on the top left corner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your function `reorder_corner_points(corners):`  but you didn't actually implement any sorting/ordering routine.

you have to order your points properly from top left.

if you do it properly  you don't need this at the end of your code :

```
# "rotate" -90 degrees to correct orientation
# warped = cv2.transpose(warped)
# warped = cv2.flip(warped, 0)
```

Try this :

```
    def reorder_corner_points(corners):
    Corners_ = []
    tr, tl, bl, br = [(corner[0][0], corner[0][1]) for corner in corners][0:4]
    for corner in corners:
        Corners_.append([(corner[0][0], corner[0][1])])

    Corners_ = np.reshape(Corners_, (-1, 2))
    # order the points in clockwise order
    ordered_corners = order_points(Corners_)
    return ordered_corners
```

Ordering function :

```
def order_points(pts):
# Order along X axis
Xorder = pts[np.argsort(pts[:, 0]), :]

left = Xorder[:2, :]
right = Xorder[2:, :]

# Order along Y axis
left = left[np.argsort(left[:, 1]), :]
(tl, bl) = left

# use distance to get bottom right
D = dist.cdist(tl[np.newaxis], right, "euclidean")[0]
(br, tr) = right[np.argsort(D)[::-1], :]

return np.array([tl, tr, br, bl])
```

Comment: I realized the original code won't work correctly if the top right corner is higher than the top left corner, and this is what causes it to rotate an extra. Weirdly enough all of my sample images has the top left corner higher so this went by undetected for a long time. If I understand your code correctly, I guess that's what it does?

Comment: What does this line do: `D = dist.cdist(tl[np.newaxis], right, "euclidean")[0]` I can't install `dist` for some reason and would like to find another way around this, preferably using `numpy`

Comment: So just make your  euclidian distance function.  It measures  the distance  between  two points.

Comment: As you are already using opencv try :  D = cv2.norm(tl[np.newaxis] - right, cv2.NORM_L2)[0]

Comment: To respond to your first question ; Yes always print your "cv2.getPerspectiveTransform" InputArray src, InputArray dst points and check manually if they are ordered.

Comment: `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` occurs on: `D = cv2.norm(tl[np.newaxis] - right, cv2.NORM_L2)[0]` I tried using `np.expand_dims(tl, axis=0)` since I thought that was the idea, but still got the error.