# I want to remove the black noise at the border of the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am looking for a way to remove the black dots around the image border using OpenCV.

Image:

[image]

Expected solution:

[image]

```
import cv2 

def get_img(img_name):
    lower = (0, 0, 0)
    upper = (75, 75, 75) 
    img = cv2.imread(img_name)
    #print(img)
    img_rgb_inrange = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    neg_rgb_image = ~img_rgb_inrange
    w = cv2.cvtColor(neg_rgb_image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    image3 = img-w
    cv2.imwrite('img.png', image3) 

get_img('address of the img')
```

I used the above code that I saw in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145306/remove-background-text-and-noise-from-an-image-using-image-processing-with-openc). The results are below:

---

output mask  I got after running the code:

[image]

Final Output:

[image]

Wondering, is there any dynamic way (instead of initializing upper and lower bounds) where I can remove the noise from the image but still maintain my foreground and background?

Comment: compression artefacts. figure out: why they happen, how much they are, why your processing is sensitive to them. -- is this a PNG, with alpha channel? then opencv won't show that. it will show the RGB data, regardless of transparency. if those pixels are supposed to be transparent, then they are allowed to have arbitrary RGB data. -- [mre] please.

Comment: There should be a more straightforward way, right? I have a mask why am I not able to substract it straight away?

Comment: MRE please. that includes input data (no screenshots).

Comment: I am working on the same data it's not a screenshot. For this conversation's sake, I downloaded the image from this page and ran that code :(. Not sure what else are you expecting me to do.

Comment: wait, _that is your input_? I thought you were working on some other input, and _that_ noisy stuff was the accidental result? you shouldn't ask how to fix this, but how to _prevent_ it from happening.

Comment: The binary artefacts that you see are most probably the result of a mis-decoding of a JPEG stream or inappropriate processing applied to it. You'd better understand where it comes from, instead of trying to "hide" it later.

Comment: Note: “image border” is the border between inside and outside the image, the first and last row and column of the image.  You are talking about the edge of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = cv2.imread('E3BbU.jpeg')
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
image2 = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(image=image2, contours=sorted(contours, key=len)[:-1], contourIdx=-1, color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)
for i, img in enumerate([image, image2]):
    ax[i].imshow(img);
    ax[i].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax[i].axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm when I used                                                                                                  
 ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 230, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) for all other images. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that. Was just about to point out that in order to get better results, this may require some tweaking of the threshold and line thickness parameters, but looks like you already did.

Comment: why are you sorting contours by number of border points?

Comment: Why are you using matplotlib? The user doesn't that.

Comment: @toyotaSupra What do you mean by "the user doesn't that"?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz to be able to ignore the biggest contour (which is not part of the black noise) when drawing