# why this fake deskewing using cvWarpPerspective doesn't work?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Executing cv::warpPerspective for a fake deskewing on a set of cv::Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838487/executing-cvwarpperspective-for-a-fake-deskewing-on-a-set-of-cvpoint)

I'm working on deskewing an image using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838487/executing-cvwarpperspective-for-a-fake-deskewing-on-a-set-of-cvpoint) .However i'm not getting the result as expected and instead getting this
[output http://imadev24.com/op.jpg](http://imadev24.com/op.jpg)

Here's my code:

```
int main() {
    const IplImage *input = cvLoadImage("input.jpg");
    IplImage *output = cvCloneImage(input);
    cvNamedWindow("Input", 1);
    cvShowImage("Input", input);

    CvMat* mmat = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    //CvPoint2D32f* c1 = (&cvPoint2D32f(41,21), &cvPoint2D32f(241,41), &cvPoint2D32f(22,201), &cvPoint2D32f(260,181));
    CvPoint2D32f* c1 = (&cvPoint2D32f(43,18), &cvPoint2D32f(280,40), &cvPoint2D32f(19,223), &cvPoint2D32f(304,200));
    CvPoint2D32f* c2 = (&cvPoint2D32f(0,0), &cvPoint2D32f(320,0), &cvPoint2D32f(0,240), &cvPoint2D32f(320,240));
    mmat = cvGetPerspectiveTransform(c1, c2,mmat);
    cvWarpPerspective(input, output, mmat,CV_INTER_LINEAR);
    cvNamedWindow("Output", 1);
    cvShowImage("Output", output);
    // wait key for 5000 ms
    cv::waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
}
```

I'm a newbie in image processing and couldn't figure out whats wrong. Could anyone point me where i was wrong in implementing this ?

Comment: what are the contents of mmat after the function call?

Comment: also are you sure those points map to the corners of the shape?

Comment: @Hammer yeah i'm sure that they map to the corners in the correct order

Comment: @karlphillip well that code wasn't working for me and hence i wanted to know whats wrong with it ...commenting on a year ago thread works ?