# OpenCV Draw draw contours of 2 largest objects

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a OpenCV software that detects boxing gloves therefore i want to detect and draw only 2 largest contours (one for each boxing glove).

My software draws contours for everything and some things are noise only which ofcourse i dont want

My code for drawing contours:

```
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(mBlur, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,  CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
    vector<Rect> boundRect (contours.size());
    vector<Point2f> boundingBoxArea(boundRect.size());

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------->

    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
     { 
       approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
       boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );

     }

    /// Draw polygonal contour + bonding rects
   Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( range_out.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
        {

           Scalar color = Scalar(0,0,255);
           drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
           fillPoly(drawing, contours, Scalar(255,0,0));

       }
```

Here is an Image Example:

[image]

My program already segments the gloves by color, The problelem is that at times small contours are drawn in random locations due to noise. Now of course the gloves contours are by far dominant and this is why i want to keep only the contours of these. Hope this makes my question clearer

Could someone suggest a solution please
I am coding in C++ environment 
regards

Comment: You should post an example image.

Comment: @Tomazi Please review the answers carefully, and up vote the ones that helped you. You can also click on the checkbox near an answer to select it as the official answer to your question.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to look at the two largest contours is to simply look at the contours size. Something like this should do the trick:

```
int largestIndex = 0;
int largestContour = 0;
int secondLargestIndex = 0;
int secondLargestContour = 0;
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    if(contours[i].size() > largestContour){
        secondLargestContour = largestContour;
        secondLargestIndex = largestIndex;
        largestContour = contours[i].size();
        largestIndex = i;
    }else if(contours[i].size() > secondLargestContour){
        secondLargestContour = contours[i].size();
        secondLargestIndex = i;
    }
}
Scalar color = Scalar(0,0,255);
drawContours( drawing, contours, largestIndex, color, CV_FILLED, 8);
drawContours( drawing, contours, secondLargestIndex, color, CV_FILLED, 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `vector<vector<Point> > contours` stores all your contours. What you need to do is iterate on this vector and do a little arithmetics with it elements, to be able to detect the 2 largest contours in the vector.

[On this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532779/176769) I shared code that detects the largest contour in a `vector<vector<Point> >`, so you are half way there.