# How to find coordinates of largest rectangle in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I have the following code:

```
    findContours( src, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( src.size(), CV_8UC3 );

    double largest_area = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {  // get the largest contour
        area = fabs( contourArea( contours[i] ) );
        if( area >= largest_area ){
            largest_area = area;
            largest_contours.clear(); 
            largest_contours.push_back( contours[i] );
        }
    }

    if( largest_area >= 3000 ){   // draw the largest contour if exceeded minimum largest area 
        drawContours( drawing, largest_contours, -1, Scalar(0,0,255), 2 );
    }
```

... which produces the following output image:

[image]

I want to get coordinates of four points (marked with green), is that possible?

Comment: It's hard to tell for a computer if a contour is a rectangle. Try [`cv::approxPolyDP()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=approxpoly#approxpolydp) on your largest contour with a reasonable epsilon parameter, it should produce a 4-sided, 4-cornered polygon for approximately-quadrangular shapes.

Comment: try HoughLinesP function

Comment: There's [some stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13532779/176769) here that's [ready for grabs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26242885/176769).

Comment: Or you can just iterate on the vector, and write a little logic to find the `cv::Point` of the corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you trying to find corners of rectangle in perspective?

You may want to try several solutions:

1. Use `HoughLines` for line detection and find their intersection.
2. Use [Generalized Hough Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_Hough_transform)
3. Use [Harris corner detector](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/trackingmotion/harris_detector/harris_detector.html). But you need to filter extra corners.

For similar task I used following procedure (it works fine in my case):
do `cv::approxPolyDP` for input contour with increasing epsilon parameter until it returns 4 or less polylines. If it returns 4 polylines you may get 4 corner points exact what you need. If it returns less than 4 polylines most probably something is wrong.