# Trapezoid to Rectangle

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, transformation

I am collecting frames from Camera and trying to do some image processing and OCR on them. When the camera is perpendicular to the target, i have no problem with cropping and image processing. But when i try to capture the frame with angle, the target expectedly turns into a Trapezoid rather than rectangle.

I am using OpenCV for all the image processing stuff. I was wondering , what can i do to get the area that i want when its trapezoid?

For example Can i somehow transform that trapezoid image to rectangle with OpenCV?

Thanks

Comment: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/geometric_image_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform

Comment: Thank you for the link, it was useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is called keystone correction:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystone_effect

Look at the similar question:
[Executing cv::warpPerspective for a fake deskewing on a set of cv::Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838487/executing-cvwarpperspective-for-a-fake-deskewing-on-a-set-of-cvpoint)