# Fast Trapezoid to Rectangle for Video

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing

I want to transform a trapezoid area into a rectangle. 
Example Picture (not perfectly trapezoid, but you get the idea):

[image]
to this:
[image]

I already can mark the corners of the trapezoid area and use [getPerspectiveTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html) to calculate the correct Matrix for [warpPerspective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#cv.WarpPerspective) to transform the image.

Unfortunately this transformation is really slow. Using it on ~80% of the area of a 720p webcam stream results in a drop to ~5fps. I suspect this might be because warpPerspective allows more transformation than i need.

Is there a faster way to transform an image from a trapezoid to a rectangle? (preferably using OpenCV)

More information:

- [warpAffine](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine) can be used to make affine transformations. It is faster than warpPerspective, but (if i got it correctly) you can only change the angle of a Parallelogramm.
- Somewhat related but without an answer: [Trapezoid to Rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926800/trapezoid-to-rectangle)

A Minimum Working Example (not fully working) based on the answer of AldurDisciple using the first picture in my post.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
int main() {

    //Mat img = imread("EQ9in.png");
    Mat img = imread("C:\\ss819729\\Aufnahmen\\arbeiten\\EQ9in.png");
    int height = img.rows;
    int width = img.cols;

    vector<Point2f> corners_rectangle, corners_trapezoid;

    corners_rectangle.push_back(Point2f(0, 0));
    corners_rectangle.push_back(Point2f(img.cols, 0));
    corners_rectangle.push_back(Point2f(img.cols, img.rows));
    corners_rectangle.push_back(Point2f(0, img.rows));

    corners_trapezoid.push_back(Point2f(35, 6));
    corners_trapezoid.push_back(Point2f(419, 55));
    corners_trapezoid.push_back(Point2f(404, 44));
    corners_trapezoid.push_back(Point2f(10, 477));

    Mat_<float> H_rectangle_to_trapezoid = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(corners_rectangle, corners_trapezoid);

    cv::Mat_<float> mapx_32f(height, width), mapy_32f(height, width);
    for(int y = 0; y<height; ++y) {
        float *buff_mapx = ((float*) mapx_32f.data)+y*width;
        float *buff_mapy = ((float*) mapy_32f.data)+y*width;
        for(int x = 0; x<width; ++x) {
            cv::Mat_<float> pt(3, 1);
            pt(0) = x;
            pt(1) = y;
            pt(2) = 1;
            pt = H_rectangle_to_trapezoid*pt;
            pt /= pt(2);
            buff_mapx[x] = pt(0);
            buff_mapy[x] = pt(1);
        }
    }
    cv::Mat map1_16u, map2_16u;
    cv::convertMaps(mapx_32f, mapy_32f, map1_16u, map2_16u, CV_16SC2);

    cv::Mat img_rectified;
    cv::remap(img, img_rectified, map1_16u, map2_16u, cv::INTER_LINEAR);

    namedWindow("Rectangle Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    while(waitKey(1)!='q') {
        cv::remap(img, img_rectified, map1_16u, map2_16u, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
        imshow("Rectangle Image", img_rectified);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Is the position of the camera and thus the warp constant, or does it need recalculation every frame?

Comment: It's constant. I have thought about doing some kind of static mapping, but didn't know how to do that. My c++ knowledge is basic.

Comment: Do a one time initialize which creates the transformation matrix and store that in a cv::Mat, use that in your main loop. 
If you provide some of your code, or a link to it it is easier to see any problems.

Comment: The Computation is already done only one time. I will however construct a minium working example.

Comment: if quality is not crucial, you may sample down the HD image before  any processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the warping transformation is constant, there is a much faster way than using `warpPerspective` at each frame, using function `remap` ([documentation link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap)). This function can be used as follows.

First, at the begining of your program, compute the transformation maps, containing the `(x,y)` coordinates in source image for each pixel of the source image:

```
cv::Mat_<float> corners_rectangle, corners_trapezoid;
// TODO: fill corners_rectangle and corners_trapezoid
cv::Mat_<float> H_rectangle_to_trapezoid = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(corners_rectangle, corners_trapezoid);
cv::Mat_<float> mapx_32f(height,width), mapy_32f(height,width);
for(int y=0; y<height; ++y)
{
    float *buff_mapx=((float*)mapx_32f.data)+y*width;
    float *buff_mapy=((float*)mapy_32f.data)+y*width;
    for(int x=0; x<width; ++x)
    {
        cv::Mat_<float> pt(3,1);
        pt(0) = x;
        pt(1) = y;
        pt(2) = 1;
        pt = H_rectangle_to_trapezoid*pt;
        pt /= pt(2);
        buff_mapx[x] = pt(0);
        buff_mapy[x] = pt(1);
    }
}
cv::Mat map1_16u,map2_16u;
cv::convertMaps(mapx_32f,mapy_32f,map1_16u,map2_16u,CV_16SC2);
// Keep map1_16u & map2_16u, discard the rest
```

Then at each frame, you only need to do the interpolation using the `remap` function:

```
cv::Mat img_rectified;
cv::remap(img_src, img_rectified, map1_16u, map2_16u, cv::INTER_LINEAR);
```

Since the computation of the coordinate transformation is done offline, this is much faster than using `warpPerspective` repeatedly.

Comment: That looks very promising! Just two question:
1. How do you fill Mat_<float> corners_rectangle? I used vector< Point > until know.
2. I think mapx should be mapx_32f.

Comment: Good catch, I corrected it, along with a small mistake when filling `buff_mapx` and `buff_mapy`. For your first question, you can do just as you did before for the `getPerspectiveTransform` call: `vector<Point>` arguments should work too.

Comment: Just a little remark: The type of map1_16u is actually CV_16SC2, only map2_16u is of type CV_16UC1, so the variable names are not 100% correct ;)